# Community, please show some holiday spirit!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash-2012

Why does [Community get hats](http://winterba.sh/leaderboard)? And more importantly: **why does she not wear them?**

[image: Community wearing]

Please, show some goddamn holiday spirit! Can we get Community to wear her hats, either randomly or through popular vote?

Comment: link please ..?

Comment: The hats earned might not be her favourite ones ;)

Comment: @NullPointer one the [main leaderboard page](http://winterba.sh/leaderboard) (at least for now), or on any site-specific leader board…

Comment: @NullPointer - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1

Comment: Nice catch. It seems that the Community is also just an user :-)

Comment: Two questions: Why do you assume that community is a female user? And secondly - and maybe more important: Why does community downvote (the propeller-hat indicates that)?

Comment: @Spontifixus I must assume Community is a person, not a thing… and then, why would I assume it is a male user?

Comment: @F'x good question. For we don't know. I was just curious, because me too thinks of the community user as a female user... ;) Maybe because "Community" in German is a female word...

Comment: All awesome AI is female. Just look at Shodan.

Comment: **Don't “not constructive”-vote me!** Nothing is more constructive than ensuring the wearing of hats by omnipresent artificial intelligences!

Comment: @Spontifixus: Whenever you flag a post as spam, community downvotes it for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I forgot about that. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: @todofixthis “goddamn” is not vulgar or offensive… the *New Oxford American Dictionary* merely marks it as “informal”. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: @rekire specifically Community is -1 on every SE site, but we all knew that. Welcome to Meta, may you never leave. _aaaahhmeehhnnnn_

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sure, why not! Well, here on Meta at least.

Also from now on, moderators can choose their community user's hat. If she has any, of course.

[image: community user with hat]

Comment: Does it decide on its own what hat to wear? ;)

Comment: Oh man - I can't wait!

Comment: Roll this out to every site!! :D

Comment: Only on MSO? Or will this work on other sites as well?

Comment: @jrg You will be able to change the hat for http://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community, which is probably your question :) We may not roll this out today though; in our current alternate datacenter we're a bit more conservative with deploying, since we don't quite have the same resources there.

Comment: She?  `Community`'s a girl?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm just going with the OP there.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: [well, bubbles is a girl, so therefore community probably is too](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/meet-bubbles/)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Community hasn't had a gender for a long time. Personally, I like her being a girl. :D

Comment: @jrg: That is the greatest costume I've ever seen :O

Comment: @Aarthi: Applejack is best pony.