# How are hats for the Community user selected?

Tags: support, community-user, winter-bash

On *English Language & Usage*, I noticed that even the [Community](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user has hats.

[image: screenshot]

In its case, how is the hat it is wearing selected?

Comment: Seems pretty obvious to me. Moderator = Police

Comment: Damn! I am using the "Howdy Pardner" one where I am moderator. Oh well... `;)`

Comment: You mean, who authenticates as Community♦  and explicitly selects that hat? Right?

Comment: I see the Community user downvotes posts... how does that work.

Comment: @tchrist Well, if the hat is not picked up by some C# code lines. `:)`

Comment: @dbaseman Those are the down-votes given, for example, to posts flagged as spam, or questions closed as off-topic.

Comment: So, the next question is - What hats are the possible ones that Community is able to get?

Comment: @JonW That is easy: All the hats given for something Community user can do. `;)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Moderators have the ability to choose the Community♦ user's hats. You should be able to find your friendly local moderator in your site's chatroom!

Comment: Oh! So I can change the one used from Community user on Drupal Answers! Why am I the last one to know things? `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but my hunch is that the Stack employees whose job is “Community Coordinator” (or the like) can actually authenticate as the Community♦ user to do something manually like this.

Either that, or a developer.

Comment: You're not *wrong* -- I (a Community Manager) can choose the Community♦ user's hats, but it's more because of *my* ♦ than my employee status. :)

Answer (score 1):

There was a [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159273/187824) for that whose [status was completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159296/187824) by [balpha ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha)