# Can Community get secret hats?

Tags: support, community-user, winter-bash-2015, secret-hats

The Community user can get hats, just like any other user, and moderators of a site can [dress its Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159273/community-please-show-some-holiday-spirit/159296#159296) in her hats.

But can she earn *secret* hats?

Currently she has only these 5 hats, none of which are secret:

[image]

I'm wondering because of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats/271029#comment878538_271029), but also more generally.

Comment: Well, I don't think there's a hard-coded restriction in place preventing her from getting secret hats. But as for auto comments that are deleted, the deletion is most likely not directly associated with the Community account, more like some DB trigger, so no hat for those.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Those comments are marked "deleted by Community" (for those who can see deleted comments), so it seems she "owns" those deletions in the same way that she owns the votes, etc. that earned her the other hats. (Of course it's entirely possible that I don't know the exact criteria for that hat, and that she hasn't earned it. I'm just curious.)

Comment: hmm... so probably something is different in the backend, e.g. "null" in the "DeletedBy" field, that for display purpose replaced with the Community user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing preventing this from happening per se.

However, there *are* hats which the Community User cannot possibly earn (for example, the Community User can never get a badge, so it cannot earn El Dorado or Cerro de Potosi).

Whether or not the requirements of any and/or all the secret hats are such that the Community User can in fact meet them – that is, well, a secret :)

Comment: Well it seems that the Community User [can get a badge](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_badges)

Comment: Yes, to be precise it would have to be "can never get a badge *on a Q&A site*". But since you can only earn hats on Q&A sites (in particular, you can't on Area51), that should be clear from the context.