# How does Community have a hat on?

Tags: discussion, community-user, winter-bash

How does Community have a hat on? On site to site, it changes, but how?

Comment: Someone with access to it probably thought it would be fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators have the ability to change which hat Community is wearing (and have <s>for at least since last year</s> [since 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159273/community-please-show-some-holiday-spirit/159296#159296)).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Since [2012](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159273/community-please-show-some-holiday-spirit/159296#159296) actually

Comment: We can choose hats! I'll be right back!